# Problem related to placement of @misc

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using bibliographystyle{unsrt}

But unable to put the @misc categories at their expected places in spite of using the key field. They are automatically placed from the top. Can anyone help me with this?

**The following is the code.**

```
%% pdf settings
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
\else
  \pdfcompresslevel=9
  \pdfimageresolution=600
  \pdfpkresolution=600
  \pdfoptionpdfinclusionerrorlevel=0
\fi

\newcommand{\InsertFigure}[4]
{
  \begin{figure}[tp]
    \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}
      \caption{#3}
      \label{#4}
    \end{center}
  \end{figure}
}

\documentclass[oneside,openright,titlepage,headinclude,11pt,footinclude]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdfspacing,dottedtoc,subfig]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,marginparwidth=0mm,marginparsep=0mm,left=28mm,right=32mm,top=25mm,bottom=38mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}

\SetKwRepeat{Do}{do}{while}

\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}

\hypersetup{%
    colorlinks=false, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV,%
    % uncomment the following line if you want to have black links (e.g., for printing)
    %colorlinks=false, linktocpage=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, pdfstartpage=3, pdfstartview=FitV,% 
    breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,%
    plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,%
    hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O,%hyperfootnotes=true,%nesting=true,%frenchlinks,%
    urlcolor=webbrown, linkcolor=RoyalBlue, citecolor=webgreen, %pagecolor=RoyalBlue,%
    %urlcolor=Black, linkcolor=Black, citecolor=Black, %pagecolor=Black,%
    pdftitle={Scalability of compression algorithms and its applications},%
    pdfauthor={Jan Platos},%
    pdfsubject={Habilitation thesis},%
    pdfkeywords={data compression, image compression},%
    pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX},%
    pdfproducer={LaTeX with hyperref and classicthesis}%
}

\newcommand{\SquareU}{{\tt\char`\ }} 
\newcommand{\SquareUbf}{{\tt\bf\char`\ }} 

\newcommand{\blob}{\rule[.2ex]{1ex}{1ex}}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listofusedpapers}{List of included papers}
\newlistof{usedpaper}{up}{\listofusedpapers}

\newcommand{\UsedPaper}[3]{%
\refstepcounter{usedpaper}
\newpage
\phantomsection
\label{#2}
\addcontentsline{up}{usedpaper}
{\protect\numberline{\theusedpaper}#1}\par
\includepdf[pages=-]{#3}}



%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

\begin{document}  
\pdfbookmark[0]{Title pages}{Title pages}
\frontmatter

\input{inc/titlepage}
\input{inc/titleback}

\input{inc/dedication}

%\input{inc/motto}
\newpage
\input{inc/preface}
\newpage
\input{inc/acknowledgments}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables
\listofusedpaper

\mainmatter


\input{content}

\chapter{Author's Publications}
\input{publication}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{intro,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6}

\end{document}
```

**ch3 bib file looks like this.**

```
@ARTICLE{Huarng2006,
    author = {K. Huarng and TH-K Yu},
    title = {The application of neural networks to forecast fuzzy time series},
    journal = {Physica A: Stat Mech Appl},
    year = {2006},
    volume = {363},
    pages = {481--491}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Mitrpanont2002,
    author = {J. L. Mitrpanont and A. Srisuphab},
    title = {The realization of quantum complex-valued backpropagation neural network in pattern recognition problem},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of 9th International Conference on Neural  Information Processing (ICONIP'02)},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2002},
    pages = {462--466}
}

@ARTICLE{Killoran2019,
    author = {N. Killoran et al.},
    title = {Continuous-variable quantum neural networks},
    journal = {Phys Rev Res},
    year = {2019},
    volume = {1}
}

@MISC{Bergholm2020,
    title={PennyLane: Automatic differentiation of hybrid quantum-classical computations}, 
    author={V. Bergholm et al.},
    year={2020},
    eprint={1811.04968},
    archivePrefix={arXiv},
    primaryClass={quant-ph}
}

@ARTICLE{Killoran2019a,
    author = {N. Killoran},
    title = {Strawberry fields: a software platform for photonic quantum computing},
    journal = {Quantum},
    year = {2019},
    volume = {3},
    pages = {129}
}

@ARTICLE{Liu2020,
    author = {Y. Liu et al.},
    title = {Variational quantum circuits for quantum state tomography},
    journal = {Phys Rev A},
    year = {2020},
    volume = {101}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Kairon2020,
    author = {P. Kairon and S. Bhattacharyya},
    title = {COVID-19 Outbreak Prediction using Quantum Neural Networks},
    booktitle = {Intelligence Enabled Research: DoSIER 2020},
    publisher = {Springer},
    volume = {1279},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {124--134}
}

@ARTICLE{Ardila2019,
    author = {D. Ardila et al.},
    title = {End-to-end lung cancer screening with three-dimensional deep learning on low-dose chest computed tomography},
    journal = {Nature Medicine},
    volume = {25},
    year = {2019},
    pages = {954--961}
}

@ARTICLE{Coudray2018,
    author = {N. Coudray et al.},
    title = {Classification and mutation prediction from non–small cell lung cancer histopathology images using deep learning},
    journal = {Nature Medicine},
    volume = {24},
    year = {2018},
    pages = {1559--1567}
}

@ARTICLE{Liao2019,
    author = {F. Liao and M. Liang and Z. Li and X. Hu and S. Song},
    title = {Evaluate the Malignancy of Pulmonary Nodules Using the 3-D Deep Leaky Noisy-OR Network},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Neural Network and Learning Systems},
    volume = {30},
    number = {11},
    year = {2019},
    pages = {3484--3495}
}

@ARTICLE{Zhu2020,
    author = {H. Zhu et al.},
    title = {MR-Forest: A Deep Decision Framework for False Positive Reduction in Pulmonary Nodule Detection},
    journal = {IEEE Journal of Biomedial and Health Informatics},
    volume = {24},
    number = {6},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {1652--1663}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{He2016,
    author = {K. He and X. Zhang and S. Ren and J. Sun},
    title = {Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of 2016 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
    year = {2016}
}

@MISC{Ma2020,
    author = {J. Ma et al.},
    title = {Towards Efficient {COVID-19} {CT} Annotation: A Benchmark for Lung and Infection Segmentation},
    howpublished = {arXiv:2004.12537},
    year = {2020},
    
}

@ARTICLE{Li2020,
    author = {H. Zhu et al.},
    title = {Using Artificial Intelligence to Detect {COVID-19} and Community-acquired Pneumonia Based on Pulmonary CT: Evaluation of the Diagnostic Accuracy},
    journal = {Radiology},
    volume = {296},
    number = {2},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {66--72}
}

@ARTICLE{Singh2020,
    author = {D. Singh and V. Kumar and Vaishali and M. Kaur},
    title = {Classification of {COVID-19} patients from chest CT images using multi-objective differential evolution–based convolutional neural networks},
    journal = {Eur. J. Clin. Microbiol. Infect. Dis.},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {1--11}
}

@ARTICLE{Roy2020,
    author = {S. Roy et al.},
    title = {Deep learning for classification and localization of {COVID-19} markers in point-of-care lung ultrasound},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
    volume = {39},
    number = {8},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {2676--2687}
}

@MISC{Wang2020z,
    author = {S. Wang et al.},
    title = {A deep learning algorithm using CT images to screen for coronavirus Disease ({COVID-19})},
    howpublished = {https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.02.14.20023028},
    year = {2020}
}

@ARTICLE{Kang2020,
    author = {H. Kang et al.},
    title = {Diagnosis of Coronavirus Disease 2019 ({COVID-19}) with Structured Latent Multi-View Representation Learning},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
    volume = {38},
    number = {8},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {2676--2687}
}

@ARTICLE{Zheng2020,
    author = {X. Zheng et al.},
    title = {A Weakly-Supervised Framework for {COVID-19} Classification and Lesion Localization From Chest CT},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
    volume = {39},
    number = {8},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {2615--2625}
}

@MISC{Yan2020,
    author = {Q. Yan et al.},
    title = {{COVID-19} Chest CT Image Segmentation–A Deep Convolutional Neural Network Solution},
    year = {2020},
    url = {https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10987}
}

@ARTICLE{Wang22020,
    author = {J. Wang et al.},
    title = {Prior-Attention Residual Learning for More Discriminative {COVID-19} Screening in {CT} Images},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
    volume = {39},
    number = {8},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {2572--2583}
}

@ARTICLE{Han2020,
    author = {Z. Han et al.},
    title = {Accurate Screening of {COVID-19} Using Attention-Based Deep 3D Multiple Instance Learning},
    journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
    volume = {39},
    number = {8},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {2584--2594}
}

@ARTICLE{Konar2020,
    author = {D. Konar and S. Bhattacharyya and T. K. Gandhi and B. K. Panigrahi},
    title = {A Quantum-Inspired Self-Supervised Network Model for Automatic Segmentation of Brain {MR} Images},
    journal = {Applied Soft Computing},
    volume = {93},
    year = {2020},
    pages = {1--21}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Konar12019,
    author = {D. Konar and S. Bhattacharyya and B. K. Panigrahi},
    title = {QIBDS Net: A Quantum-Inspired Bi-Directional Self-supervised Neural Network Architecture for Automatic Brain {MR} Image Segmentation},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of 8th International Conference on Pattern Recognition and Machine Intelligence (PReMI 2019)},
    volume = {11942},
    pages = {87--95},
    year = {2019}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Konar22019,
    author = {D. Konar and S. Bhattacharyya and S. Dey and B. K. Panigrahi},
    title = {Opti-QIBDS Net: A Quantum-Inspired Optimized Bi-Directional Self-supervised Neural Network Architecture for Automatic Brain {MR} Image Segmentation},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of TENCON 2019},
    pages = {761--766},
    year = {2019}
}

@ARTICLE{Bhatt2007,
    author = {S. Bhattacharyya and P. Dutta and U. Maulik},
    title = {Binary object extraction using bi-directional self-organizing neural network (BDSONN) architecture with fuzzy context sensitive thresholding},
    journal = {Pattern Analysis and Applications},
    volume = {10},
    year = {2007},
    pages = {345--360}
}

@ARTICLE{Bhatt12011,
    author = {S. Bhattacharyya and P. Dutta and U. Maulik},
    title = {Multilevel image segmentation with adaptive image context based thresholding},
    journal = {Applied Soft Computing},
    volume = {11},
    number = {1},
    year = {2011},
    pages = {946--962}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Konar32016,
    author = {D. Konar and S. Bhattacharya and U. Chakraborty and T. K. Gandhi and B. K. Panigrahi},
    title = {A quantum parallel bi-directional self-organizing neural network (QPBDSONN) architecture for extraction of pure color objects from noisy background},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of IEEE International Conference on Advances in Computing, Communications and Informatics (ICACCI)},
    pages = {1912--1918},
    year = {2016}
}

@ARTICLE{Konar42016,
    author = {D. Konar and S. Bhattacharya and B K. Panigrahi and K. Nakamatsu},
    title = {A Quantum Bi-Directional Self-Organizing Neural Network (QBDSONN) Architecture for Binary Object Extraction from a Noisy Perspective},
    journal = {Applied Soft Computing},
    volume = {46},
    year = {2016},
    pages = {731--752}
}

@ARTICLE{Dey2014z,
    author = {S. Dey and I. Saha and S. Bhattacharyya and U. Maulik},
    title = {Multi-level Thresholding using Quantum Inspired Meta-heuristics},
    journal = {Knowledge Based Systems},
    volume = {67},
    year = {2014},
    pages = {373--400}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Hou2016,
author = {L. Hou et al.},
title = {Patch-based Convolutional Neural Network for Whole Slide Tissue Image Classification},
booktitle = {Proceedings of 2016 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR)},
pages = {2424--2433},
year = {2016}
}

@ARTICLE{Sharma2017,
author = {A. Sharmaa and X. Liua and X. Yangb and D. Shic},
title = {A Patch-based Convolutional Neural Network for Remote Sensing Image Classification},
journal = {Neural Networks},
volume = {95},
year = {2017},
pages = {19--28}
}

@INPROCEEDINGS{Kervrann2006,
author = {C. Kervrann and J. Boulanger},
title = {Unsupervised Patch-Based Image Regularization and Representation},
booktitle = {Proceedings of 2006 European Conference on Computer Vision (ECCV)},
volume = {3984},
pages = {555--567},
year = {2006}
}

@ARTICLE{Oh2020,
author = {Y. Oh and S. Park and J. C. Ye},
title = {Deep Learning COVID-19 Features on CXR using Limited Training Data Sets},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging},
volume = {39},
number = {8},
year = {2020},
pages = {2688--2700}
}

@MISC{Soares2020,
    author = {E. Soares and P. Angelov and S. Biaso and M. H. Froes and D. K. Abe},
    title = {SARS-CoV-2 CT-scan dataset: A large dataset of real patients CT scans for SARS-CoV-2 identification},
    howpublished = {https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.04.24.20078584},
    year = {2020}
}

@MISC{Jun2020,
    author = {M. Jun et al.},
    title = {COVID-19 CT Lung and Infection Segmentation Dataset (Version 1.0) [Data set]},
    howpublished = {Zenodo.http://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3757476},
    year = {2020}
}

@ARTICLE{Yan2020z,
    key = {ZZ6},
    author = {T. Yan},
    title = {{CCAP}},
    journal = {IEEE Dataport, 2020},
    year = {2020},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.21227/ccgv-5329}
}


@ARTICLE{Guerrero2018,
author = {R. Guerrero et al.},
title = {White matter hyperintensity and stroke lesion segmentation and differentiation using convolutional neural networks},
journal = {NeuroImage: Clinical},
volume = {17},
number = {8},
year = {2018},
pages = {918--934}
}

@ARTICLE{Fernando2020,
author = {T. Fernando et al.},
title = {Heart Sound Segmentation Using Bidirectional LSTMs With Attention},
journal = {IEEE Journal of Biomedical and Health Informatics},
volume = {24},
number = {6},
year = {2020},
pages = {1601--1609}
}

@ARTICLE{Gail1976,
author = {M. H. Gail and S. B. Green},
title = {Critical Values for the One-Sided Two-Sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov Statistic},
journal = {J. Am. Stat. Assoc.},
volume = {71},
year = {1976},
pages = {757--760}
}

@ARTICLE{Little2007,
    author = {M. A. Little et al.},
    title = {Exploiting Nonlinear recurrence and Fractal scaling properties for voice disorder detection},
    journal = {Biomedical Engineering},
    year = {2007},
    volume = {6},
}


@ARTICLE{Sahni2020,
    author = {S. Sahni and V. Aggarwal and A. Khanna and D. Gupta and S. Bhattacharyya},
    title = {Quantum-inspired evolutionary algorithms for neural network weight distribution: A classification model for Parkinson's disease},
    journal = {Journal of Information and Organizational Sciences},
    year = {2020},
    volume = {44},
    number = {2},
    pages = {345--363}
}
```

All these @MISC entries are being placed at the top of all other references.

Comment: you are using `unsrt` so no sorting happens and entries appear in the order they are cited in your document. (I don't know any bibtex style that sorts @misc differently to @article or other bib tyypes)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, those misc entries without author names are placed at the top. I am facing this problem in spite of using unsrt where other entries appearing in the order they are cited.

Comment: Thanks. I am compiling a thesis with separate bib files for different chapters. A snap of the code is as follows.                                                                \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{intro,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6}                                                                            ch3.bib contains several @misc entries, which are placed above the entries generated by all the other bib files.

Comment: you added some tex code(but we can not run it) nor does it show the important information of where the `\cite` are,

Comment: You might have a `\cite` command in a `\caption`, which will make the entry appear at the top in the bibliography section, because it is seen when doing the list of figures/tables. If this is the case, add `\usepackage{notoccite}` to the list of packages.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ch3.bib` provided in the question and this test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


article Killoran2019a \cite{Killoran2019a}

article Huarng2006 \cite{Huarng2006}

misc Bergholm2020 \cite{Bergholm2020}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{ch3}
\end{document}
```

You get this output

[image]

Where as you see the items are listed in the order they are cited and the item type `@ARTICLE` or `@MISC` has does not affect the numbering in any way.

If you are seeing the items in a different order then that will be due code not shown, you could edit the question to make an example.